# Pandas: find average month/day at which yearly event occurs

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas df that contains two time columns. These columns contain the yyyy-mm-dd of yearly event.

**How is it possible to calculate the average mm-dd of the occurrence of the event over all years?**

I guess this involves counting (for each line) the number of days between the actual date and the Jan-1 of the year, but I don't see how to do that efficiently with Pandas.

Thank you!

```py
    dormancy1   greenup1    maturity1   senescence1 dormancy2   greenup2    maturity2   senescence2
8   2002-08-31  2002-04-27  2002-05-06  2002-08-21  NaT NaT NaT NaT
22  2003-09-17  2003-06-06  2003-06-15  2003-07-22  NaT NaT NaT NaT
36  2004-09-10  2004-04-20  2004-05-15  2004-05-24  NaT NaT NaT NaT
44  2005-08-13  2005-04-24  2005-06-29  2005-07-18  NaT NaT NaT NaT
74  2007-05-10  2007-03-13  2007-04-07  2007-05-01  NaT NaT NaT NaT
95  2009-09-18  2009-04-26  2009-05-06  2009-06-03  NaT NaT NaT NaT
113 2010-09-09  2010-05-29  2010-06-08  2010-07-19  NaT NaT NaT NaT
```

**Edit:**
Complete steps to reproduce error:

```py
# Create and format data
df = pd.DataFrame({'dormancy1': ['2002-08-31','2003-09-17','2004-09-10','2005-08-13','2007-05-10','2009-09-18','2010-09-09'],
'greenup1': ['2002-04-27','2003-06-06','2004-04-20','2005-04-24','2007-03-13','2009-04-26','2010-05-29'],
'maturity1': ['2002-05-06','2003-06-15','2004-05-15','2005-06-29','2007-04-07','2009-05-06','2010-06-08'],
'senescence1': ['2002-08-21','2003-07-22','2004-05-24','2005-07-18','2007-05-01','2009-06-03','2010-07-19'],
'dormancy2': ['NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT'],
'greenup2': ['NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT'],
'maturity2': ['NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT'],
'senescence2': ['NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT','NaT']})

df['dormancy1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dormancy1'])
df['dormancy2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dormancy2'])
df['greenup1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['greenup1'])
df['greenup2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['greenup2'])
df['maturity1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity1'])
df['maturity2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity2'])
df['senescence1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['senescence1'])
df['senescence2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['senescence2'])

# Define the function
def computeYear(row):
    for i in row:
        if pd.isna(i):
            pass
        else:
            return dt.datetime(int(i.strftime('%Y')), 1, 1)
    return np.nan

df['1Jyear'] = df.apply(lambda row: computeYear(row), axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime((x - df['1Jyear']).values.astype(np.int64).mean()).strftime('%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

Convert your data in datetime format if it is not already done:

```
df['dormancy1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dormancy1'])
df['greenup1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['greenup1'])
```

Get the 1st January of the year of the row (I assumed that your events on one row occure the same year):

```
df['1Jyear'] = df['dormancy1'].dt.year.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x, 1, 1))
```

This is how your dataframe looks now:

```
df.head()
     dormancy1    greenup1      1Jyear
0   2002-08-31  2002-04-27  2002-01-01
1   2003-09-17  2003-06-06  2003-01-01
2   2004-09-10  2004-04-20  2004-01-01
3   2005-08-13  2005-04-24  2005-01-01
4   2007-05-10  2007-03-13  2007-01-01
```

To get the average month and day of each event:

```
df[['dormancy1', 'greenup1']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime((x - df['1Jyear']).values.astype(np.int64).mean()).strftime('%m-%d'))
```

This outputs the following series:

```
dormancy1    08-10
greenup1     04-30
```

Let me know if this is the required result, I hope it will help you.

### Update: Handle Missing Data

### Update2: Handle empty columns

I'm working with the following data:

```
    dormancy1   greenup1    maturity1   senescence1 dormancy2   greenup2    maturity2   senescence2
8   2002-08-31  2002-04-27  2002-05-06  2002-08-21  NaT NaT NaT NaT
22  2003-09-17  2003-06-06  2003-06-15  2003-07-22  NaT NaT NaT NaT
36  2004-09-10  2004-04-20  2004-05-15  2004-05-24  NaT NaT NaT NaT
44  2005-08-13  2005-04-24  2005-06-29  2005-07-18  NaT NaT NaT NaT
74  2007-05-10  2007-03-13  2007-04-07  2007-05-01  NaT NaT NaT NaT
95  2009-09-18  2009-04-26  2009-05-06  2009-06-03  NaT NaT NaT NaT
113 2010-09-09  2010-05-29  2010-06-08  2010-07-19  NaT NaT NaT NaT
```

To compute the year of each row (I get the first year I find in the column so again I assume it is the same year for every event, but if it is not the same you would need to compute different columns for every events) :

```
def computeYear(row):
    for i in row:
        if not pd.isna(i):
            return dt.datetime(int(i.strftime('%Y')), 1, 1)
    return np.nan
df['1Jyear'] = df.apply(lambda row: computeYear(row), axis=1)
```

To get the result:

```
df.apply(lambda column: np.datetime64('NaT') if column.isnull().all() else\
     pd.to_datetime((column - df['1Jyear']).values.astype(np.int64).mean()).strftime('%m-%d'))
```

Output:

```
dormancy1      08-20
greenup1       04-29
maturity1      05-21
senescence1    06-28
dormancy2        NaN
greenup2         NaN
maturity2        NaN
senescence2      NaN
1Jyear         01-01
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just an unforeseen thing... Is there a way to adapt that if the Dataframe contains some `NaT`?

Comment: I edited my answer to handle the missing data, can you confirm it resolved your issue ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately not – I poorly exposed the problem, apologies! I edited my initial post to show the complete df. The problem is that there are a lot of missing data (very scattered dataset!). I think it is safe to assume that `dormancy1` will be complete, so we can use it to compute the `1Jyear` as you initially proposed. Now, I get the following error when I try to get the results:
`ValueError: ('NaTType does not support strftime', 'occurred at index dormancy2')`

Thank you for your help. I tried to figure it out myself but did not manage, I am fairly beginning with python.

Comment: Can you show me the code you used by editing your question with every steps with if possible the creation of a small DataFrame so that we work on the same data? I don't succeed to reproduce your error.

Comment: Now it should work ok (I edited my answer), because your column was empty, it couldn't compute the strftime cause the mean returned a NaT so I just handled this case by putting a NaN. Maybe there is a better solution but this should work :).

Comment: Wooo, would have never figured that out! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now what you want to use here is the old **`pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear`** function. That will tell you how many days into the year a specific date occurs. This has probably flipped the switch in your mind and you're building the answer right now, but just in case:

```
avg_day_dormancy1 = df['dormancy1'].dt.dayofyear.mean()

# Now let's add those days to a year to get an actual date
import datetime as dtt  # You could do this in pandas, but this is quick and dirty
avg_date_dormancy1 = dtt.datetime.strptime('2000-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')  # E.g. get date in year 2000
avg_date_dormancy += dtt.timedelta(days=avg_day_dormancy1)
```

Given the data you provided I got August 10th as the average date on which `dormancy1` occurs. You could also call the `.std()` method as well on the `dayofyear` Series and get a 95% confidence interval for which these events occur, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. Hope this helps

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
```

Calculating the average day of the year for both events

```
mean_greenup_DoY = df['greenup1'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple().tm_yday).mean()
mean_dormancy_DoY = df['dormancy1'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple().tm_yday).mean()
```

This initially converts the date string to datetime object and then finds the day of the year using the logic in lambda function, on this mean() is appliead to get the avg day of the year.